# What is the difference between "from keras.models import Sequential" and "from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential"?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm using Tensorflow 1.14 and Python 3.5. 
I got the following error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment`

The full trace back is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
   1237                                         steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
   1238                                         validation_steps=validation_steps,
-> 1239                                         validation_freq=validation_freq)
   1240 
   1241     def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py in fit_loop(model, fit_function, fit_inputs, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_function, val_inputs, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq)
    203                     break
    204 
--> 205             if batch_index == len(batches) - 1:  # Last batch.
    206                 if do_validation and should_run_validation(validation_freq, epoch):
    207                     val_outs = test_loop(model, val_function, val_inputs,

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_index' referenced before assignment
```

And after trying multiple suggestions from different SO answers, I managed to fix it by switching from these import statements:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
```

To these import statements:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
```

This did resolve my issue, but I am puzzled: How are the two any different?

Are `tf.keras` and `keras` using different methods and classes?

Comment: Please include the full traceback, and yes, keras and tf.keras do not have the same underlying implementation

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro done.

Answer (score 3):

Difference between tf.keras and keras.

- **Keras:** Is a high level neural network API for training neural networks. It's independent of `tensorflow` and can run on top of multiple backends such as `tensorflow, Theano and CNTK`. Documentation [here](https://keras.io/)
- **tf.keras:** `tf.keras` is a specific high level implementation of the `keras` API in tensorflow with added support for certain `tensorflow` features.